# How to override react-router-link Link style properties?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, react-router

I am trying to simply change the color of each displayed Link in the app:
[image]

The default color is blue as you see.
Since Link *depends* on the **html a** tag, I went to this **App.scss** file and tried to override it:

> App.scss

```
// Styles
// Customizing link color
a {
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
  color: rgb(109, 5, 5);
}
// CoreUI Icons Set
@import "~@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css";
// Import Flag Icons Set
@import "~flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css";
// Import Font Awesome Icons Set
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
// Import Simple Line Icons Set
@import "~simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css";
// Import Main styles for this application
@import "./scss/style.scss";
```

However, still nothing changed. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you're importing scss/styles.scss after your changes. So your changes need to be after all imports even then you need to check the `specificity` override any classes that applying the style

Comment: I didn't get the specificity part

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: browsers use `specificity` to decide how styles are applied. very simple example: lets say you have `<a class='link' >`. In css element is styled `.link {color: red}`. Then even if you do `a {color: blue}` it will remain red because using class = higher specificity than element tag.  so you'd have to add `.link {color: blue}` at the bottom of the file to make it blue.There is a lot more to it than this but this is just very simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be your load order.

What is probably happening here is that you are setting

```
a {
  color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
  color: rgb(109, 5, 5);
}
```

And after that, you are importing styles that probably have `color` properties on `a` and `a:hover` and your style is overridden.

In most cases you should put imports at the top of your files and then write your custom code/styles/whatever.